# how to put an array item to the end in php?

Tags: php

how to put an array item to the end in php?
I want to put some item of array to the last position , when I loop and output the $arr to html, this will keep the 'other' item always at the end. what is the best and easy way to do it?

```
<?php
$arr=array(
    'a'=>'hello',
    'game'=>'boy',
    'other'=>'good',
    'name'=>'jimmy',
    //...
);


// how to resort $arr to put other item to then end of $arr
$arr=array(
    'a'=>'hello',
    'game'=>'boy',
    'name'=>'jimmy',
    //...
    'other'=>'good'
);
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're not simply asking to sort the array based on the alphabetical property of the keys, given your array:

```
$arr=array(
    'a'=>'hello',
    'game'=>'boy',
    'other'=>'good',
    'name'=>'jimmy',
);
```

You have to take the old key out first, while saving its value:

```
$old = $arr['other'];
unset($arr['other']);
```

Then, append it to the array like this:

```
$arr += array('other' => $old);
```

Answer (score 2):

with the example you have given `ksort($arr)` would sort it alphabetically and put the `other` item to the end.

second option is to remove the `other` item from the array using `array_slice` and then placed it in the back using `array_merge`

Comment: `array_slice()` can't search on key value.

Answer (score 1):

First store all the element that you required.

Like

`$arr=array(
    'a'=>'hello',
    'game'=>'boy',
    'name'=>'jimmy');`

After that add

```
$arr['other']='good';
```

Now other element is always at last.....